# How to execute Casper JS TestSuite with some delay between each TestCase?

Tags: casperjs, slimerjs

I have one basic_function.js script file which contains some validation and frequently used operations. Like I said below is the validation part (example)

```
exports.validation = function (casper) {
return casper
.then(function () {
    this.exists('1st Element ID',"Log Out button exist");
    this.exists('2nd Element ID', "Shareable link exists");
    });
};
```

which is used in every single script just by calling

```
functions.validation (casper);
```

When I start executing the test suite (comprises of around 10-12 test scripts), some times the 1st few scripts gets passed with the validation part and some scripts gets failed with the validation part and in log it prints that

## failed to find matching element for Shareable link

and in next script it gets passed.
I dont have any idea why it is behaving like this

Comment: This question is far too broad. You need to investigate the problem. Maybe it's a session issue.

Comment: I didn’t get you.. Could you elaborate about it?..

Comment: Are some of the test cases dependent on a clean session? If so, then you need to clear cookies and maybe clear the localStorage.

Comment: Not even single test cases are dependent up on each other...

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this what you're asking but I had to add some waiting time to my CasperJS scripts in order to avoid failures. Here's a couple of ways:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.wait(1000, function(){
        test.assertTitle('The Title', 'It all works');
    });
});
```

or you can wait for a specific element to appear on your page and then execute your assertions etc.

```
casper.then(function(){
    casper.waitUntilVisible('#someID', function(){
        test.assertTitle('The Title', 'It all works');
    });
});
```

[Here's the documentation for you to check out](https://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#wait)

Comment: appreciate your answers but I have given enough amount of time to page load and then validating

Answer (score -1):

Some code may be helpful to make the problem more clear.. But if you are running a bunch of tests and have code changing the thing you are testing in between said tests, then you may need to wait after you change the options. To make it clearer I'll provide an example of what I'm trying to say. I do a lot of website testing with casper so this is my best guess as to might be what is happening (on some level) If I write a test that opens the home page. Types something into a search bar, then instantly tests for something on the results page. It will error because there is load time obviously switching from pages to pages, and you cannot test the result page without waiting a second or two. So typically I use a casper.waitForSelector() but in your case you may want just a casper.wait() in which you hard code a time that you deem sufficient.